# How can we solve this integral equation?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, integral-equations

The following equation seems extremely simple:

$$
    g(b)=\int_1^{\frac{1}{b}} \frac{X f(X)}{\sqrt{1-b X}} \, dX
$$

But how to solve it, that is, restore the function $f(X)$ from the known function $g(b)$? Maybe this is some well-known integral transformation, which I was not told about at the university? Additionally, we can assume that $f(1)=0$.

Comment: Why not take derivatives on both sides and solve for $f(b)$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi: This yields `f -> Function[{X}, X^(-((-3 + 2 b + n)/(-1 + b))) C[1]]` but f[X] should be independent of `b` in case when `g[b]=(1-b)^(n-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** a complete solution, just two ideas which are too large for a comment

let us define helper function $h$, so that:
$$g(b)=h(1/b), $$

now we have $$h(t) = \int_1^{t} \frac{X f(X)}{\sqrt{1- X/t}} \, dX
$$
and use chain rule with fundamental theorem

$h'(t)=\frac{tf(t)}{\sqrt{1-t/t}}$

since we get division by zero corollary is not enough and we may have to go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

In particular

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_a^{x} f(x,t)dt\right) = f(x,x)+\int_a^{x} \frac{d}{dx}f(x,t) dt$$

or if we are comfortable with Fourier transforms we can possibly use convolution theorem with Fourier transform of

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}$

Comment: Thank you so much. Your advice helped. Initially I underestimated the convolution method by stupid reason.